# "An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type." – what should I use instead?

Tags: typescript

When I try to compile this Typescript code

```
interface Foo { 
    [foo: "hello" | "world"]: string;
}
```

I get this error message

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

What is a mapped object type, and how do I use it?

Answer (score 216):

A mapped object type operates on a set of singleton types and produces a new object type where each of those singletons is turned into a property name.

For example, this:

```
type Foo = {
    [K in "hello" | "world"]: string
};
```

would be equivalent to

```
type Foo = {
    "hello": string;
    "world": string;
};
```

Keep in mind that a mapped object type is a distinct type operator - that syntax in the braces can't be used in interfaces, or object types with other members. For example

```
interface Foo {
    [K in "hello" | "world"]: string; // ❌
}
```

produces the following error:

```
A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

Mapped object types are useful for a lot of different things. Read more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Comment: Is there a version of this where the type can have only one property whose name must be either `hello` or `world`?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out too: how do you make a type that has either `hello` or `world` prop and be able to narrow typing to use the correct type...

Comment: I want to point out the difference. To make a mapped type we replace the  **":"** with **" in "**. And becomes `[foo in "hello" | "world"]`

Comment: Note the answer changes `interface` to `type` - this was the fix for me.

Comment: @ironchicken, yes, you simply need to add `?` after closing `]`, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700831/449553

Comment: @ironchicken You could do `type Foo = { hello: string; world?: never; } | { world: string; hello?: never }`. You can also extend this to accept a generic union/value to make it reusable: `type Foo = OnlyOneProperty<"hello" | "world", string>`. See [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-onlyoneproperty-72xy5?file=/index.ts) for example usage.

Comment: @DanielThompson I've been searching for daaaaays for information like this. Thank you so much for linking to the playground.

Answer (score 17):

This is invalid:

```
    type DirectiveType = 'package-as' | 'externals' | 'move-folders' | 'ignore';
    type Directives = { [key:DirectiveType]?: RootDirectives };
    
    export class PkgmetaFile {
        private _directives: Directives = {};
    }
```

But this is valid:

```
    type DirectiveType = 'package-as' | 'externals' | 'move-folders' | 'ignore';
    type Directives = { [Key in DirectiveType as string]?: RootDirectives };
    
    export class PkgmetaFile {
        private _directives: Directives = {};
    }
```

Comment: Could you give more insight about your answer? Trying to understand an answer without an explanation might lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: I was able to infer a key to a mapped object from a union type by simply using 'as string' at the end of 'DirectiveType'

Comment: This is the better answer as it preserves the ability to specify a key type and have multiple interfaces use that type as a key.  The accepted answer is more limited in scope and almost useless for my needs.

Comment: this seems to accept any string for the key, not only DirectiveType

Comment: it also works on enums directly like this, thanks.
enum example: `{[k in EMyEnum as string]: boolean}`
instead of `k` for "key" you can use whatever make sense for you, and as an example it's a boolean value, but of course you want to adapt.

Comment: What @mrtnmgs says though, this removes any restrictions from the key name.