# How to use enum as index key type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, indexing, enums

Consider following example.

```
enum DialogType {
    Options,
    Help
}

class Dialog { 
    test() : string {
        return "";
    }
}

class Greeter {

    openDialogs: { [key in DialogType]: Dialog | undefined } = {
        0: undefined,
        1: undefined
    };

    getDialog(t: DialogType) {
        return this.openDialogs[t];
    }
}

const greeter = new Greeter();
const d = greeter.getDialog(DialogType.Help);
if (d) document.write(d.test());
```

[Also in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20DialogType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Options%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Help%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dialog%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test()%20%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20openDialogs%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20DialogType%5D%3A%20Dialog%20%7C%20undefined%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%3A%20undefined%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getDialog(t%3A%20DialogType)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.openDialogs%5Bt%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20d%20%3D%20greeter.getDialog(DialogType.Help)%3B%0D%0Aif%20(d)%20document.write(d.test())%3B)

There are 3 issues/questions with it:

1. Why I cannot omit properties in my initializer literal, even though I declare properties as '| undefined'
2. Why I cannot use 'DialogType.Options' as type key, and have to use hardcoded number instead?
3. Why do I have to use 'key in DialogType' instead of 'key: DialogType'? (Or can I? )

Comment: **See Also**: [Use Enum as restricted key type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243060/1366033)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

1. `|undefined` does not make a property optional, just means it can be `undefined`, there is a proposal to make `|undefined` members optional but currently it's not implemented. You need to use `?` after `]` to make all properties optional

   ```
   { [key in DialogType]?: Dialog }
   ```
2. You can use the dialog enum values as keys, but they need to be computed properties:

   ```
   let openDialogs: { [key in DialogType]?: Dialog } = {
       [DialogType.Options]: undefined,
   };
   ```
3. `{ [key: number or string]: Dialog }` is an index signature. Index signatures are restricted to only `number` or `string` as the key type (not even a union of the two will work). So if you use an index signature you can index by any `number` or `string` (we can't restrict to only `DialogType` keys). The concept you are using here is called mapped types. Mapped types basically generate a new type based on a union of keys (in this case the members of DialogType enum) and a set of mapping rules. The type we created above is basically equivalent to:

   ```
   let o: { [DialogType.Help]?: Dialog; [DialogType.Options]?: Dialog; }
   ```

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you so much! I was convinced that 'T?' was equivalent to 'T | undefined', especially after seeing this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#optional-parameters-and-properties. So is optional type equivalent to something or is it kind of a thing on it's own?

Comment: @ironic It goes one way but not the other a property of type `T?` will be considered `T|undefined` for null checking, but a property of type `T|undefined` willnot be considered optional

Comment: What id I wanted to specify a different member type for each key? something like : `let o: { [DialogType.Help]: DialogHelp; [DialogType.Options]: DialogOptions; }`

Comment: @neomib you can do it manually like in your example, if there is some mapping rule I would need to see it to offer a better solution

Comment: `key in` ended up being the _key_ part I was missing. ;) Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly when declaring this as a named `interface` - rather than in-line - I get a TS error (4.8.4): `A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.`. However, declaring it as a named `type` is totally fine.

Comment: Rather than specifying all available options (like this: "[DialogType.Help]: DialogHelp; [DialogType.Options]: DialogOptions;"), you can use this: "[key in DialogType]" - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use enum as index in typescript:

```
enum DialogType {
    Options,
    Help,
    About
}
type Dialog = {
    whatever: string;
};
type DialogMap = { [key in DialogType]?: Dialog };

let o: DialogMap = {
    [ DialogType.Options ]: { whatever: "1" },
    [ DialogType.Help ]: { whatever: "2" }
};
```