# Typescript: Map enum to property keys of a class

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-generics

Let's say we have an enum like the following:

```
export enum HeroActionEnum {
  STRIKE = 'strike',
  HIDE = 'hide',
  RUN = 'fly',
  TACKLE = 'tackle',
}
```

now we create a new class with attributes which have the exact same keys represented in the `HeroActionEnum`.

```
export class Hero {
  [HeroActionEnum.STRIKE]: EventEmitter<void>;
  [HeroActionEnum.HIDE]: EventEmitter<void>;
  [HeroActionEnum.RUN]: EventEmitter<void>;
  [HeroActionEnum.TACKLE]: EventEmitter<void>;
  ...
}
```

The DRY principle is not happy about this. I would actually like to sum the keys up like:

```
export class Hero {
  [key in HeroActionEnum]: EventEmitter<void>;
  ...
}
```

I tried a lot but I got nothing to work so far. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: yeah, I tried something similar in the past, do you have tried use an object instead an enum? just a guess

Comment: @DavidNithaelTorresLima yes i already tried a `const allHeroActions = [ 'strike', 'hide', ...]` but also without success.

Comment: [Maybe this can help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700831/14097137)

Comment: Unfortunately not the question :/

`let hero: { [key: HeroActionEnum]: EvenEmitter<void>}` works without a problem.

but no idea how to implement this into a class.

Comment: What about `abstract class AbstractHero { actions: { [key: HeroActionEnum]: EventEmitter<void> }}`?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but yes this resolves the issue as well and is the solution i went with thanks! :) still would be interesting if there is a way to assign class attributes by an enum but i don't think so.