# typescript generic to make object have keys ONLY (but not necessarily all) from list of names

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

### What i want

I have a type with known values

```js
type Possibilities = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

And want to be able to create object that can **only** have **keys** that belongs to that type, but **not** necessarily all of then.

And also prevent each prop's type from outputing as `string | undefined`
[image: img]

As it is meant to be used on constants, that have fixed values. And TS can already infer proper typing:
[image: img]

So, it should accept:

```js
const mine = {
    a: "this",
    b: "and",
    c: "that"
}
const yours = {
    b: "it"
}
```

But should *not*:

```js
// not known key ( 'x' )
const theirs = {
    a: "these",
    x: "those"
}
// preferably - empty object
const noOnes = {}
```

---

### I've tryed:

- If i do one of bellow

  ```js
  const mine: Record<Possibilities, string>;
  const mine: {[key in Possibilities]: string};
  ```

  it says the obj must have all the keys. Wrong.
- If i do one of

  ```js
  const mine: Partial<Record<Possibilities, string>>;
  const mine: {[key in Possibilities]?: string};
  ```

  it allow me to set only some, however, types gets out as `string | undefined`. Even if "casting" object `as const`.
- `Pick<>` or `Omit<>`, for every single "instance" created, makes the desired result, but it's a pain in the ass, and kind of repeating myself (need to write `"a", "b"...` on type and again on value).
  [image: img]
  Also, at least here, `Omit<>` is not even auto-completing the possible values. Making it even harder and/or error prone when using most of possibilities, by needing to pick a lot or omit 'blindly'.

I got a feeling that the solution is somewhere close by using a generic that may extend the type... But couldn't figure it out.

#### --- EDIT ---

@tokland comment took me to an "almost there" [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/188031)

```js
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]

type Possibilities = "a" | "b" | "c"

let mine: AtLeastOne<Record<Possibilities, string>>;
```

This enforces the object to have a, b or c prop.
Forbids it to have unknown props.
And correctly outputs prop's type as not "possibly undefined"

[image: img] [image: img] [image: img]

But it breaks apart when multiple allowed props are set

[image: img]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "types get out as ... | partial though i've set the value". Maybe this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types ? Some code on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play would be helpful.

Comment: I mean, if  i set a `const x: Partial<...> = {a="abc"}` the type of x.a is `string | undefined` (in VS Code at least) because it's been set to be optional.

That's not what i want. I want it o "inter" type just as if not type was set. But limit with props are allowed on atribution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate. I'll link the answer. It's not pretty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/188031

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell, it is not related at all

Comment: @tokland, nice. That typing trickery ALMOST thie the thing. `const mine: AtLeastOne<Record<Possibilities, string>>` does output the type of prop (say mine.c) as `string` only. But it breaks if more than one props is set, and all become `string | undefined`

Answer (score 3):

With TypeScript 4.9 and above you can achieve this with the [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies).

This allows you to ensure a value satisfies a type, without applying that type to it.

```
const mine = {
  a: 'this',
  b: 'that',
} satisfies Partial<Record<Possibilities, string>>;
```

If you use this with `as const`, you can even get the exact string values as their type, rather than just `string`, and make all the keys readonly.

E.g. in the below example the type of `mine.a` is `'this'`, and it cannot be modified.

```
const mine = {
  a: 'this',
  b: 'that',
} as const satisfies Partial<Record<Possibilities, string>>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
// Here you can include all the keys you want
enum Possibilities {
    a = "a",
    b = "b",
    c = "c",
}

type OtherType = {
    [key in Possibilities]?: {}; // here the sign ? allows you to set the keys as optional
}
// valid
let A: OtherType = {
    a: {}
}
// valid
let C: OtherType = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
    c: {},
}

// also valid
let B: OtherType = {}
```

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700831/6673107) for more explanation about the topic

Comment: Hey, as stated in the "I've tryed" part, `Partial<...>` (or `{[...]?:...}`) outputs for each props' type as `... | undefined` https://imgur.com/ui13Xvq

I want it's type to be "as required". Just the variable not needing to set ALL the keys

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for this:

```
type Possibilities = "a" | "b" | "c"

type OnlyPossibilities<P extends string | number | symbol, T> = T extends {
  [key in P]?: any
} ? T : never

type Foo = OnlyPossibilities<Possibilities, {
  a: number
}>

type Bar = OnlyPossibilities<Possibilities, {
  d: number
}>
```

(Link to the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEbIDbOMiCoC8UARAIbFQA+JqF1xAxsQLABQbokUA8gHYYh4SNJmy4EAHhhQIAD2AReAE3wJgAJ2S8A5lSi8ArgFtUEdXoQgTcDABooAFQB8hRzPmKVUAN5soUAG0AawgQKC1YAF0AfgAuKFJeEDYAXyhot3jeCAA3MzYOcGgAMTg4Vz4BIRR0LBw8KUQa0XqEe19Wf1Is41N1VKcC1k5oACFScyJKwSaROvFG4VqxPHa-KCUek3zWFMHWIA))

Here I am declaring a helper type which accepts both the possibilities, `P`, and the type you want to check, `T`. `Foo` will correctly be of type:

```
type Foo = { a: number }
```

...but `Bar` will be:

```
type Bar = never
```

thus "not allowing any values".

You can also get rid of `P`, I just used it to make the helper type customizable:

```
type Possibilities = "a" | "b" | "c"

type OnlyPossibilities<T> = T extends {
  [key in Possibilities]?: any
} ? T : never
```

If you have `any` banned, you should be able to use `unknown` instead.