# Typescript object type - how to use integer enum as key

Tags: typescript, enums

I am trying to use an integer Enum as a key for an object type and it generates the error I included in the comments:

```
enum Enum {
  first = 1,
  second = 2,
  third = 3,
}

type EnumAsKey = {
  [key in Enum]: string; //<-- Type 'Enum' is not assignable to type 'string'
};
```

Shouldn't Enum be assignable to type `number` and can't a number be used as an index here?

How do I achieve this?

I have also tried:

```
[key: Enum] <- An index signature parameter type must be 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or a template literal type.
[key: typeof Enum[keyof typeof Enum]] <-- Type 'Enum' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Related, but this solution only appears to work when the enum is of strings:
[How to use enum as index key type in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700659/how-to-use-enum-as-index-key-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Can you provide a playground link? I can't reproduce the error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQVVQGYEsBOBnALlALxQCMANCmrsAMYD2IAJsVAEyVpT4AWOLJAMyUAvkiT4AngAdgseAEFcAaWCTWyLgG0A1mqiYQ8yAF0AXFALZDAcwDcUAPSOAPAFo3UACoy5AcjhIPwNcKBB6QgBDXFxMGxBIgCMAGzl8em5fKD8rWz8kETskIA)

Comment: Strange! I'll have to investigate whether this is a case of the repository using an older version of TS and will update as appropraite.