# Only allow a certain set of strings as keys in interface

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to change the below so that the nested object can only have a certain set of keys, let's say `foo` or `bar`, and allows, but does not require, all of the set.

```js
interface ConfigObject {
    [key:string]: {
        [key:string]:string
        // this compiles, and allows any number of keys (good), but allows any string as the key (bad)
    }
}
```

I tried changing to

```
interface ConfigObject {
    [key:string]: {
        "foo"|"bar":string
    }
}
```

but this fails to compile as a syntax error, also tried putting in an array, parentheses. A single string works but not multiple.

I can do:

```
interface ConfigObject {
    [key:string]: {
        [K in "foo"|"bar"]:string
    }
}
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659490/8940624)

But this makes `foo` AND `bar` required, so a nested object with only `foo` or only `bar` will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last implementation was close, you just need to mark the properties as optional using the `?` operator:

```
interface ConfigObject {
    [key: string]: {
        [key in "foo" | "bar"]?: string;
    };
}
```