# Typescript object key with index

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wnat to declare key with index like

```
interface myType {
        delivery_name1: string;
        delivery_name2: string;
        delivery_name3: string; 
        delivery_name4: string; 
        delivery_name5: string;
        ...n(20)
   }
```

I tried

```
  type Index ="1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"  ...
    type delivery_name = `delivery_name${Index}`

interface myType {
    [key: delivery_name]:string;
}
```

But got error.
`An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead`

How to solve it ?

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659490/10100812

Comment: @Edwin It is solved, if you want leave an answer 
I will check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `interface` for the type in this case. Please use a `type` instead:

```
type Index ="1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
type delivery_name = `delivery_name${Index}`

type myType = {
    [key in delivery_name]: string;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDygXgEQEYNQD5QYBMuBGAzKYQCxUYCsdAbHQOx0AcdAnBgFChIUJABsAlgDcIAJxAB9OAEMAttDRQABqMkz5S1QBIA3vCTIAvhr4Dw0ZSAAqt9FCN8oHqAG0A1hBBQYnDCEOJSsgoqEAC6AFxQAM7A0kEA5gDcfOZAA)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659490/10100812)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Edwins excellent answer, if you want to do this n times...

```
type MakeSeries<T extends number,R extends unknown[] = []> = T extends R['length'] 
? never
: [...R,unknown]['length'] | MakeSeries<T, [...R, unknown]>


type Index = MakeSeries<20> // <-- n times
type delivery_name = `delivery_name${Index}`

type myType = {
    [key in delivery_name]: string;
}
//**
type myType = {
delivery_name1: string;
delivery_name2: string;
delivery_name3: string;
delivery_name4: string;
delivery_name5: string;
delivery_name6: string;
delivery_name7: string;
... 12 more ...;
delivery_name20: string;
**//
```

}

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgawgZQgJwJYQM4B4AqUEAHsBAHYAm2U5ArgLYBG6ANFAEpGkXVR3kE5APYB3cgG0AulAC8UaQD45UQiTJUaHCQHIANhQDmwABY6ZAKAD8qiwC5Oug+WNmZAH1iIU6LHnzsEgB0IRzsAkJi5FKKFnGgkFAAklQkKvBIqJg4uABMAAyxCdCUEHoYAG7oIAD65HAM0PIABqXlVWi19Y0AJADeKaXEAL7N8eDQDCD4Eyp9FlCLCkggUBjkUG2V1XUNEFIO2MCYLgDcFsMWQA)

Comment: WOOOOW THNAKS!!!

Comment: That's really cool!~